# VS2015: WDK 10 "Unable to start debugging"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, driver, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging, wdk

I just finished installing WDK in VS 2015. In addition to WDK I also setup a VM with Win10 and installed & configured the WDK test environment there. I setup a simple Hello World project and was able to build, deploy & apparently run the driver.

The problem is that debugging does not really work. VS just tells me "Unable to start debugging" ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdoIY.png ). It also tells me to check my debugging settings, but that doesn't help either. The only thing I can specify here is which computer I want to deploy/debug on ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Rth.png ). I also tried attaching the Kernel Debugger to the VM. Didn't work either: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfiNE.png (VS crashed).

The output window doesn't really help either - From the text there you get the impression that everything is working just fine ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO1ST.png ). Are there any other logs I can check?

VS & WDK are both up-to-date. The Hello World project is based on Microsoft's KMDFHelloWorld tutorial ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439665(v=vs.85).aspx -> also followed the steps for deployment & installation).

Any ideas?

*PS: Merry Christmas!*

Edit:
I tried connecting using WinDbg, this is what happened: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH7yv.png (connection refused). Settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9cW3.png - VS Settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qGZC.png

Edit #2:
Ran bcdedit /enum all, here are the results: http://pastebin.com/pgUyW5kL

Comment: Did you tried to attach to the VM using `windbg` or `kd` just to see if the kernel debugging setup (without VS) is at least correct?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried `windbg`, connecting using http://i.imgur.com/9yrtNlT.png - This is how I connect: http://i.imgur.com/UhJiyBD.png - Result: http://i.imgur.com/TYe2ksf.png (10061, connection refused). Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, nothing looks really strange... It might comes from the debugging config though. Could you edit your message and add the whole bcdedit config of your VM? The command should be `bcdedit /enum all`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this. Here are the results: http://pastebin.com/pgUyW5kL (partly in German, sorry). I took a look at "Debuggereinstellungen" (Debugger settings), and the port (40451) matches the port of VS / windbg settings.

Comment: `bcdedit` config looks OK to me, I'm out of ideas... In a last effort and for testing purpose I'd try to disable both firewalls (host **and** VM), ensure that `192.168.56.1` is still the host IP (and **not** the VM IP, seems obvious but double checking doesn't do any harm) and finally use a simpler key like `1.2.3.4` (modify it with bcdedit and reboot).

Comment: Well, something seems wrong with the IP then I guess. This is `ipconfig` on the host computer: http://i.imgur.com/j2ZeEBk.png - You'll notice `192.168.56.1` there. That is not an actual IP address. Neither the VM knows that IP (VM `ipconfig` says `192.168.0.31` which is correct). Could that be the issue? The Host IP is `192.168.0.16`